# Unable to return right object from Json

Tags: json, ruby, selenium-webdriver

I've used json for the below selenium ruby syntax

```
@driver.find_element(:css, "#poi-tabs *[class='tab ']")
```

---

This works as expected

```
@driver.find_element(:css, JSON.parse(file)['xyz']['elemen'])
```

But the below **FAILS** to work, since the value `:css` taken from .json file is not supporting here

```
@driver.find_element(JSON.parse(file)['xyz']['selecto'], JSON.parse(file)['xyz']['elemen'])
```

**Note:**
When I print "selecto" and "elemen", both brings the exact output but not sure about the format; is there any format to handle it ? or any other workaround

[image]

---

Available **or.json**

```
{
  "xyz": {
    "selecto": ":css",
    "elemen": "#poi-tabs *[class='tab ']"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@driver.find_element(:css, JSON.parse(file)['xyz']['elemen'])
```

Here :css is a symbol whereas in

```
@driver.find_element(JSON.parse(file)['xyz']['selecto'], JSON.parse(file)['xyz']['elemen'])
```

:css is a string. So you are not getting desired result.

Try

```
@driver.find_element(eval(JSON.parse(file)['xyz']['selecto']), JSON.parse(file)['xyz']['elemen'])
```